# How to autowire/inject JIRAs CustomFieldManager / ComponentAccessor in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, jira, autowired

I am using JIRA 7.1.6 and always get an exception

> *No qualifying bean of type
>   'com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager' available...*

when trying to annotate a CustomFieldManager property in my service within a SpringBoot application. The same happens when I try using the ComponentAccessor.

How can I solve this problem?

In the meantime I found out that in spite of using CustomFieldManager the ComponentAccessor shall be used:

```
CustomFieldManager cfm = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(CustomFieldManager.class);
CustomField cf = cfm.getCustomFieldObjectByName(k);
```

...but I get the same exception.

Here's the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.xxxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>zzzz</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>TheApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <jira.version>7.1.6</jira.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.13.3</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.26</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jta</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.atlassian.fugue</groupId> <artifactId>fugue</artifactId> 
        <version>2.6.1</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version> -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.7.25</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>jirakpm</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                        <mainClass>
                            de.vwncova.defectadapter.JiraKpmAdapterControllerAndMain
                        </mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <!-- <repository> <id>Attlassian-Maven-Legacy</id> <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-closedsource-legacy/</url> 
        </repository> -->
    <repository>
        <id>Central Repository</id>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Attlassian-Maven-External</id>
        <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-hosted-atlas-external/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Attlassian-Maven</id>
        <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Attlassian</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Attlassian-3d-Party</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Start by showing us some code

Comment: And include the POM.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that I try to access the `ComponentAccessor` not from the same VM my SpringBoot application is running in. There is my SpringBoot application on the one hand trying to access the JIRA server on the other hand via REST API (which are obviously running in different VMs). 
The `ComponentAccessor` is only accessible when my code would run on the JIRA server side, for instance as a JIRA plugin. 
Hence, I cannot use the `ComponentAccessor` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

infact , if you really want to access the jira function, you should add the jira-api and jira-core and other dependency jar into your pom file, restart your springboot project with @WebListener LauncherContextListener, of course , many error happened, according the log ,resolved them, that will work.